# Most efficient way to count occurrences?

Tags: java, performance, counting

I've got an array of bytes (**primitive**), they can have random values. I'm trying to count occurrences of them in the array in the most efficient/fastest way. Currently I'm using:

```
HashMap<Byte, Integer> dataCount = new HashMap<>();
for (byte b : data) dataCount.put(b, dataCount.getOrDefault(b, 0) + 1);
```

This one-liner takes ~500ms to process a *byte[]* of length **24883200**.
Using a regular *for* loop takes **at least** 600ms.

I've been thinking of constructing a set (since they only contain one of each element) then adding it to a HashMap using *Collections.frequency()*, but the methods to construct a *Set* from primitives require several other calls, so I'm guessing it's not as fast.

What would be the fastest way to accomplish counting of occurrences of each item?

I'm using Java 8 and I'd prefer to avoid using Apache Commons if possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's just bytes, use an array, don't use a map.  You do have to use masking to deal with the signedness of bytes, but that's not a big deal.

```
int[] counts = new int[256];
for (byte b : data) {
   counts[b & 0xFF]++;
}
```

Arrays are just so massively compact and efficient that they're almost impossible to beat when you can use them.

Comment: this would work, but it'd also allocate memory for values that don't occur, I'll need the HashMap of these values later on, without the 0 values of course.

Comment: Seems the increase is so big I can afford creating a later copy to HashMap!

Comment: An `int[]` is _so_ much more compact than a `HashMap` that the "memory for values that don't occur" is almost certainly paid for by not using a `HashMap`.  Depending on how large the counts are, the `int[256]` is better if you have even ~20 distinct bytes, and all the other 236 values are 0.

Answer (score 8):

I would create an *array* instead of a `HashMap`, given that you know exactly how many counts you need to keep track of:

```
int[] counts = new int[256];
for (byte b : data) {
    counts[b & 0xff]++;
}
```

That way:

- You never need to do any boxing of either the keys or the values
- Nothing needs to take a hash code, check for equality etc
- It's about as memory-efficient as it gets

Note that the `& 0xff` is used to get a value in the range `[0, 255]` instead of `[-128, 127]`, so it's suitable as the index into the array.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen 2 *identical* pieces of code appearing at the same time before.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: The code from Louis has capital hex digits, and three spaces instead of 4 :)

Comment: His came first, that's why accepted it, since there's no big difference :)